# Как передать POST запрос с русскими буквами / failed to decode JSON object

Tags: python, json, flask, requests

Есть код:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from main import pipe

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/neuron_net', methods=['POST'])
def get_class():
    if not request.json or not 'text' in request.json:
        return jsonify({'error': 'empty text'})
    info = pipe(request.json['text'])
    message = {'text': request.json['text'],
                'id_class': info[0],
               'class': info[1],
               'probability': info[2]}
    return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Мне нужно отправить запрос с русскими буквами и получить в ответ json файл , в котором есть русские буквы. То есть значение 'text' в получаемом запросе должно быть русскими буквами.

то есть при запросе:

```
{"text": "письмо во вложении"}
```

должен вывести:

```
{'text': "письмо во вложении",
                'id_class': 1,
               'class': "письмо",
               'probability': "90%"}
```

Отправляю запрос, выводит ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смените кодировку терминала. В Винде по умолчанию чуть ли cp866 кажется, а в json должна быть utf8

Comment: поменял, та же самая ошибка

Comment: Ну я бы просто сохранил JSON в файле в правильной кодирове (хоть блокнотом) и отравлял данные из файла, что бы не заморачиваться странностями винды. И, кстати, вместо ключа `-d` надо использовать `--data-binary`

Comment: Проблема явно в кодировке. А почему curl который под win даже по дефолту не идет? Может лучше поставить postman и не тратить время на написание консольных запросов? А еще лучше, написать пару юнит-тестов..